# How to automate POST request in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, express, post

I'm trying to automate my NodeJS app to automatically send POST requests every 2 minutes. Following is my code but I do not see the console logs or anything that proves me that it's working. If I'm trying the POST request via POSTMAN it's giving me the output correct. What might be wrong in my following code?

```
'user strict';
const express = require('express');
const config = require('./config');
const cors = require('cors');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const eventRoutes = require('./routes/eventRoutes')

const app = express();

app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.json());


app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    next();
  });
  
  app.get('/api', (req, res) => {
    request(
      { url: 'http://localhost:3507/api' },
      (error, response, body) => {
        if (error || response.statusCode !== 200) {
          return res.status(500).json({ type: 'error', message: err.message });
        }
  
        res.json(JSON.parse(body));
      }
    )
  });
  

var minutes = 2, the_interval = minutes * 60 * 1000;
setInterval(function() {
  app.post('/api/add', (req, res) => {
    console.log('Post Request!');
    request(
      { url: 'http://localhost:3507/api/add' },
      (error, response, body) => {
        if (error || response.statusCode !== 200) {
          return res.status(500).json({ type: 'error', message: err.message });
        }
  
        res.json(JSON.parse(body));
      }
    )
  });
}, the_interval);

app.use('/api', eventRoutes.routes)

app.listen(config.port, () => console.log(`Server is listening on http://localhost:` + config.port))
```

Comment: It looks like you're automating *creating an endpoint* every two minutes, not *sending a request* every two minutes.  Can you clarify what it is you're actually trying to do?  If your server should be sending a request every two minutes, what do you plan to do with the response?

Comment: @David Here's my goal : I have many `INSERT` and `UPDATE` `MSSQL` scripts that I need to execute. Those scripts doesn't have any user input parameters and I would like to execute those POST requests every `x` minutes. Please advice me how can I correct my code, thank you!

Comment: And those database interactions are taking place on another server entirely, not in this application?  If that's the case then the database part is essentially irrelevant here.  If the `request()` function is what you're using to perform HTTP requests then you'd just wrap *that* operation in a `setInterval`.  The `app.post()` operation is used to create an HTTP endpoint in your Express application.  That's not something you'd repeat in an interval.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is the operation performing the HTTP request that you want to repeat on an interval:

```
request(
  { url: 'http://localhost:3507/api/add' },
  (error, response, body) => {
    if (error || response.statusCode !== 200) {
      return res.status(500).json({ type: 'error', message: err.message });
    }

    res.json(JSON.parse(body));
  }
)
```

Then that's the operation you'd perform in an interval:

```
setInterval(() => {
  request(
    { url: 'http://localhost:3507/api/add' },
    (error, response, body) => {
      // do something with the response?
    }
  );
}, the_interval);
```

Note that the operation to handle the result has been removed because it doesn't make sense outside the scope of an HTTP endpoint.  (Which is what `app.post(/*...*/)` does, it creates an HTTP endpoint on your web server.  You were trying to repeat *that* operation on an interval, which doesn't really make sense.)

Note that it's **very unusual to do this**.  You're essentially sending an HTTP request from your web server to some other web server every two minutes.  The same request, over and over.  Entirely in the background and unrelated to any requests that *this* web server receives.

So it's **entirely possible** that this isn't actually what you want to do, whatever you're trying to accomplish.  But if you **do** want to repeat this task from your web server every two minutes, you'd just wrap it in a `setInterval`.

Comment: You saved my day! Thank you very much @David for the quick response. This is what exactly I was looking for. As you mentioned I got confused between creating endpoint vs executing request. Thank you for the clarification and everything!